# protractor unknown error, removing attribute from DOM

Tags: javascript, html, testing, protractor, end-to-end

Im new to protractor and trying to remove attribute from DOM but getting "unknown error", Im not sure what could be the problem

Im having a simple HTML with a custom directive.I am trying to remove that for my test cases to pass:

```
<input type="text" name="rptdate" input-date placeholder="DD-MM-YYYY" data-ng-model="newPatReports.reportDate" />
```

Commands I ran are:

```
browser.executeScript( 'document.getElementsByName("rptdate").removeAttribute("input-date")' );
browser.driver.findElement(protractor.By.name('rptdate')).removeAttr("input-date");
browser.executeScript('document.querySelector("input[name='rptdate']").removeAttribute("input-date");');
```

But none of them helped.

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki made a reverse, closed that topic as a dup - since the issue was resolved here. Thanks for pointing the other question out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Locate the element with Protractor and then pass the Web Element into the script:

```
var elm = element(by.name("rptdate"));

browser.executeScript('arguments[0].removeAttribute("input-date");', elm.getWebElement());
```

Comment: Hi spidy @alecxe can you please tell me what is arguments[0] here?